# Manga where the main character is a shadow and has a muscular slime

Tags: story-identification, manga

I read this manga a year ago and can barely remember details about it, but I know that the main character meets an almost-dead slime. He helps it and it grows into a big slime with muscles.

Later, the main character builds a spire in a desert and it explodes. Also, a demon child (I think) wants to learn from the main character and then later, there's this bear that took over as a mayor or something and is bested by main character then turned small.

Also, a game developer/assistant is following the main character then dropped some papers, then a muscular bunny picks them up (I think again). Thanks for the help.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this in full colour or mostly black & white?

Comment: @LogicDictates It was mostly full color I believe

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Final Raid Boss (published for free on [WEBTOONS](https://www.webtoons.com/en/fantasy/the-final-raid-boss/list?title_no=3921&page=1)) has [one full color muscular slime](https://www.webtoons.com/en/fantasy/the-final-raid-boss/episode-37/viewer?title_no=3921&episode_no=37):

[image: Clang clang, the slime attacks with a weapon]

It also has a [muscular bunny holding some papers about the game's development](https://www.webtoons.com/en/fantasy/the-final-raid-boss/episode-33/viewer?title_no=3921&episode_no=33):

[image: bunny holding beta testers raid boss papers]

I don't know anything else about how this might match up, but I'm not sure I need to.

Comment: thank you very much I appreciate for helping me